# This error and warning often appear when I want to run my code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

> Error MSB3027
> Could not copy "C:\Users\HP\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\obj\Debug\net7.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net7.0\ConsoleApp7.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "ConsoleApp7 (7440)" ConsoleApp7 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   5167

And

> Warning MSB3026
> Could not copy "C:\Users\HP\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\obj\Debug\net7.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net7.0\ConsoleApp7.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\net7.0\ConsoleApp7.exe' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "ConsoleApp7 (7440)" ConsoleApp7 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   5167

I am not sure the problem is from my code because I can't find any error.

Comment: you got to turn it off and on again, in other words stop your program first!

Comment: Typical anti-malware problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is already running. You need to make sure it has terminated before trying to run it again.